# Applying local GPOs to a computer disconnected from domain controller

Tags: domain, group-policy, cmd.exe

I want to apply local group policies to a number of machines. To apply group policies on a computer one can run this command:

> GPUPDATE

However, if a computer is setup on a domain, but is currently disconnected from that domain, `GPUPDATE` will fail, because it can't connect to the domain controller. Is it possible to only apply local GPOs to a machine?

Comment: There's no such thing a "local GPOs".  Any newly added local policies will (generally) be enforced upon next boot and/or user login.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to make a script run on shutdown without the need of first rebooting the computer, to apply the GPO. Shutdown scripts are not possible with Scheduled Tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fredd, Local GPOs are immediately applied (except for those who needs rebooting, so you better reboot).

Comment: But that's the problem, I want to apply them so reboot is not required likge GPUPdate does, is this really not possible?

Comment: As I said, some GP configurations require reboot, and you can't skip it (even GPUpdate doesn't).